# Concatenating text and command output in Bash script to output to file

Tags: bash, scripting, concatenation, freebsd

I'm writing a bash script in FreeBSD that appends commands to a log file. Before I execute the commands that will append the log data, I want to print a line in the file which shows the current date above the data, like this:

---Tue Aug 20 17:26:37 EDT 2019---

I know that I can use the date command to output the timestamp, but I'm not sure how to include the "---" before and after the timestamp to add to the file. What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: So many choices.  `printf '-- %s --' "$(date)"` or `printf '-- '; date | tr -d \\n; printf ' --'`

Comment: `date | sed -e 's/^/-- /' -e 's/$/ --/'`

Comment: If your implementation of `date` supports it: `date +'-- %a %b %d %T %Z --'`

Comment: Why the pain? `%FT%T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a format string to [`date`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/date/):

```
date '+---%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y---'
```

Comment: Thats perfect! Thank you all for the feedback :-).