# Printing formatted date line output to file in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, formatting, freebsd

This is a follow-up to a previous question I posted on this thread here: [Concatenating text and command output in Bash script to output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581745/concatenating-text-and-command-output-in-bash-script-to-output-to-file)

So far, I am using the following line to append a date heading to a log file, which I later add more data to:

```
date '+---%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y---' >> "./Logs/Log.txt"
```

This works fine except I would like to add a blank line aboce and below the header to better distinguish the text from the headings. I'm assuming that I would simply add a '\n' somewhere but putting it into the format string for the date command simply appends it literally to the text that goes into the file.

**EDIT:**

When I run the above command, I get the following as an output in my log file:

```
---Wed Aug 21 14:09:33 EDT 2019---
```

But what I want to do is add a blank line before and after the above line to space out the data.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, thanks to user Léa Gris's feedback. The corrected line now reads:

```
date '+%n---%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y---%n' >> "./Logs/Log.txt"
```

Comment: Please consider reading the date man-page about the format codes. `LC_TIME=POSIX date '+%n---%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y---%n' >> "./Logs/Log.txt"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `%n` at the end and beginning of the line

```
date '+%n---%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y---%n' >> Log.txt
```

From `man date` (`man`, your best friend)

```
%n     a newline
```

Answer (score 3):

Save yourself the trouble of trying to trick `date` into formatting your non-date related data.

You can instead use command substitution in a *here document* as a simple little template:

```
cat >> "./Logs/Log.txt" << EOF

--- $(date) ---
Yours truly, $(whoami)

EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this `bash`, but the `date` command is part of the operating system, not a built-in in the shell.

If you're running bash version 4 or higher (you can `echo $BASH_VERSION` to check) then you can use date formats with the `printf` built-in command.

Try:

```
printf '\n---%(%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y)T---\n\n'
```

Or just for fun:

```
printf '%(%n---%+---%n%n)T'
```

Note that if you add other placeholders to your `printf` format, you'll need to specify an actual number for this time, or `-1` for "now":

```
printf '\n---%(%+)T--- %s\n\n' -1 "Hello"
```